# SearchBox in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, searchbar

I am making a search bar using access database and listbox. the code belows searches for the item in the database, if there isn't any item it will return "no matches" and if there is a match it will show the result in the listbox.

a) However there is one problem in my program which i am not sure how to fix. when i search the same product again, it will duplicate the result. i have provided the screenshot so you can understand.

[this image shows what happens, when i search the same product again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNMDI.png)

b) is it possible to modify this search bar so that it will have a drop-down list so that the users can see ahead what they are searching.
Please help if it makes sense. Thanks

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\MS Office\project.mdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE productID LIKE '" & txtSearch_Bar.Text & "'", con)
    con.Open()
    Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()


    If Not sdr.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Matches")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    While (sdr.Read())
        lstbSearchResult.Items.Add(sdr("ProductID"))
    End While


    'lstbSearchResult.Items.Clear()

End Sub
```

Comment: Empty/Clear the previous search results at the start...almost a trick question.  Note that there are easier ways to do that using Filters; also, your app is leaking resources

Comment: You need to clear the Items collection of your listbox _lstbSearchResult.Items.Clear();_ before starting the loop

Comment: A word of advice for getting better answers; write one and only one question in each question. With that said, the text, example and image for question a was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for a):

I *guess* you want to have the old search results in the listbox, but not duplicates.

Pseudo code:

```
found = false
for each item in listbox
    if newItem = item then found = true
if not found
    listbox.add item
```

Since I am a senior developer I would of course use a dictionary which does not allow for duplicates and write the above but more convoluted. Then I would recognise my code as ugly and wrap the dictionary in an appropriately named class. After a cup of coffee I would then realise the possibility of reuse and write, inheriting or composing, a new listbox control which does not allow for duplicates. Then I would go home since writing all that code and tests and finding the correct place to put it in the project and documenting it takes a full day.